# Better way to copy from shared folder to SharePoint?

Tags: windows, file, sharepoint, directory, shared-libraries

I kindly ask, which is the better way to copy from fa *shared folder* to a *SharePoint* site.

The data volume is like 270GB and more less 900000 files.

Is there any *PowerShell* script, or by promt? Or is better to use drag and drop the mode?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using this code mentioned in [Salaudeen Rajack's blog](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/06/upload-files-to-sharepoint-online-using-powershell.html):

```
#Variables
$SiteURL = "https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"
$FilesPath = "C:\Upload"
$ServerRelativePath = "/sites/sitename/libraryname"
 
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)
 
#Get All Files from a Local Folder
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $FilesPath -Force -Recurse
 
#bulk upload files to sharepoint online using powershell
ForEach ($File in $Files)
{
    Write-host "Uploading $($File.Directory)\$($File.Name)"
  
    #upload a file to sharepoint online using powershell - Upload File and Set Metadata
    Add-PnPFile -Path "$($File.Directory)\$($File.Name)" -Folder $ServerRelativePath -Values @{"Title" = $($File.Name)}
}
```

This code uses pnp power shell to upload files in a local folder to a library in SharePoint in a loop.

There are other methods mentioned in the blog, you can choose according to your needs.
According to your description, your file size is 270GB. Because the maximum file size limit is 250 GB per file in SharePoint Online, it is recommended that you upload it in batches.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Amy Jiang_MSFT for your help.